# Can not parse xml root element use jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

**Test Bean**

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "DATA_RECORD")
public class TestBean{
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="ERROR_MESSAGE_CODE")
    private String error_message_code;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="ERROR_MESSAGE")
    private String error_message;
    //...getter/setter
}
```

**XMl Sample**

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"Windows-31J\" standalone=\"no\"?>"
            + "<Message xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" "
            //+">"
            + "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=\"TEST.xsd\">" // if comment out this,it will work.
            + "<DATA_RECORD>"
            + "<ERROR_MESSAGE>some message</ERROR_MESSAGE>"
            + "<ERROR_MESSAGE_CODE>CODE111</ERROR_MESSAGE_CODE>"
            + "</DATA_RECORD>"
            + "</Message>";
```

**Deserialize**

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
//xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
xmlMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
TestBean test = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, TestBean.class);
log.debug(test.toString());
```

I run it from Junit and I get exception like:

> Root name 'noNamespaceSchemaLocation' does not match expected
>   ('DATA_RECORD') ....

If I remove `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="TEST.xsd"` from `String xml`, it will work fine.

Have idea about this? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features#structural-conversions), when you specify `UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`, Jackson (XML here instead of JSON)

> Will verify that the root JSON value is a JSON Object, and that it has
>   a single property with expected root name. If not, a
>   JsonMappingException is thrown;

In this case the root `Message` has another property apart from `DATA_RECORD`, the XML attribute with name `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` and as specified a `JsonMappingException` is thrown.

I am afraid you will have to parse `Message` and get `TestBean` from there. E.g.:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement
class Message {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "DATA_RECORD")
    private TestBean dataRecord;
}

class TestBean {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ERROR_MESSAGE_CODE")
    private String error_message_code;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "ERROR_MESSAGE")
    private String error_message;
}
```

and

```
xmlMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
Message test = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, Message.class);
log.debug(test.getDataRecord().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.it works!!So I can not parse xml partially like take <DATA_RECORD> as root element,not <Message>?